# Drupal 6 syntax to retrieve values

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

If I make a form with the following,

```
 $form['section1']['a']['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name of student group'),
    //'#disabled' => TRUE, 
  );

  $form['section1']['b']['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name'),
   // '#disabled' => TRUE, 
  );
```

Then to refer to the values i use the following?

```
$value_a = $form_state['value']['a']['name'];
$value_b = $form_state['value']['b']['name'];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive an associative array of form values, you need set [`#tree => TRUE,`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#tree) in your parent form element.

For an example:

```
  $form['section1'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Name of student group'),
    '#tree' => TRUE,
  );
```

Now, in your submit function, you will receive an array of values for `section1`.

```
$form_state['values']['section1']['a']['name'];
```